# Check username/password in Active Directory from PC that is NOT part of domain

Tags: delphi, ldap, delphi-2010

**Edit:** I modified the code according to Andrei Galatyn's comment and hints that I shall not rely on token being nil when invalid, but it's still not working for PC's that are not part of the domain.

---

I want to verify if a user entered a username/password combination that is valid in a LDAP server.

Currently I use this code:

```
function CheckWinUserAccount(Username, Password, Domain : string) : boolean;
var token: THandle;
begin
     result:=False;
     if LogonUser( PChar(Username), PChar(Domain), PChar(Password),
                   LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, token) then
     begin
          CloseHandle(token);
          result:=True;
     end;
end;
```

It works perfectly if executed on a PC that is part of the LDAP domain, but not on a PC that only uses the LDAP PC as DNS but is not part of the domain.

My data:

- Domain: graz.local
- Username: LDTest

I tried entering the username as `LDTest`, as `graz\LDTest` and as `graz.local\LDTest`.

I also tried specifying the domain as `graz`, `graz.local`, `ldap://graz.local`

None of that worked. Any idea?

Btw: I was not sure if this is possible at all (accessing the domain server from a non-domain-PC), but using the LDAP Administrator (by Softerra) this works.

Comment: AFAIK, when combining Domain + Username, it's supposed to be a backslash ( ` \ ` ), not a forward slash ( ` / ` ).

Comment: Try LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK instead of LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE (it seems to be wrong parameter for such task).

Comment: Thanks for both your comments, I worked that in into the post, but the code still only works on machines that are part of the domain.

Answer (score 4):

<del>As noted by Andrei Galatyn use LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK instead of
LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE when calling "LogonUser". The username
should not include the domain name, the domain name can either be the
NetBIOS domain name ("graz") or the DNS domain name ("graz.local").</del>

EDIT: Using "LogonUser" only works if the client has already established a connection to the domain.

Here is the code which performs the authentication using LDAP.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  JwaWinLDAP,
  JwaRpcDce;

var
    sUsername, sDomain, sPassword, sDC : String;
    LDAP : PLDAP;
    SWAI : SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY;

begin
    if (ParamCount <> 4) then
    begin
        WriteLn ('WinLdapTest [username] [domain] [password] [domain controller]');
        Halt (1);
    end; { if }

    sUsername := ParamStr (1);
    sDomain := ParamStr (2);
    sPassword := ParamStr (3);
    sDC := ParamStr (4);

    LDAP := ldap_openW (PChar (sDC), LDAP_PORT);

    if (Assigned (LDAP)) then
        try
            SWAI.User := PChar (sUserName);
            SWAI.UserLength := Length (sUserName);
            SWAI.Domain := PChar (sDomain);
            SWAI.DomainLength := Length (sDomain);
            SWAI.Password := PChar (sPassword);
            SWAI.PasswordLength := Length (sPassword);
            SWAI.Flags := SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;

            if (ldap_bind_sW (LDAP, PChar (sDC), PChar (@SWAI),
                              LDAP_AUTH_NTLM) = LDAP_SUCCESS) then
                WriteLN ('"ldap_bind" success')
            else WriteLN ('"ldap_bind" failure');

        finally
            ldap_unbind (LDAP);
        end { try / finally }
    else WriteLn ('"ldap_open" failed');
end.
```

The code uses the [JEDI API library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/) and assumes that you're using Delphi 2009 or higher (Unicode strings). To automatically retrieve the DC name you could call [DsGetDcName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675983.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code, that's a possible way, as LogonUser does NOT work for me, even when I use LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK.. The method DsGetDcName seems to expect a big number of parameters. I tried NetGetAnyDCName(nil, domainname, buf), which returns "\\LDAPSERVER". It seems I need to remove the backslashes. With DC="LDAPSERVER" to your method works, but completely ignores sDomain. (it's not important what I pass there). Is that normal? And it's relatively slow, it takes ~2 seconds to complete.

Comment: I just had to find out, that NetGetAnyDCName does not work on a PC that is not part of the domain. I now use the code from http://www.swissdelphicenter.com/en/showcode.php?id=1272 and call it with "GetPDC('graz');" which returns "\\LDAPSERVER" just as expected.