# Get groups of a user from Active Directory from PC that is NOT part of domain

Tags: delphi, ldap, delphi-2010

I need to get a list of groups a special user is member of.
Normally I can do that using NetUserGetGroups, here's the code:

```
function GetLDapUserGroups(UserName, DomainName : string) : TStringList;
var bufptr : Pointer;
  ServerName : String;
  EntriesRead : DWord;
  TotalEntries : DWord;
  buf : Pbyte;
  PGlobalGroupInfo : PGroupInfo0;
  i : integer;
begin
     result:=TStringList.Create;

     // get servername
     // if problems occur maybe set param2 to nil
     bufptr := nil;
     NetGetAnyDCName(nil, PWideChar(DomainName), bufptr);
     ServerName := PWideChar(bufptr);
     Delete(ServerName, 1, 2);  // remove starting '\\' from server Name

     if NetUserGetGroups( PWideChar(ServerName), PWideChar(UserName), 0, buf, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
                          @EntriesRead, @TotalEntries)=NERR_SUCCESS then
     begin
          PGlobalGroupInfo := PGroupInfo0(buf);

          // Store group names in list
          for i:=0 to EntriesRead - 1 do
          begin
               result.Add(PGlobalGroupInfo^.grpi0_name);
               inc(PGlobalGroupInfo);
          end;
     end;
     NetAPIBufferFree(buf);
end;
```

but this does not work, if my program is running on a PC that is not part of the AD-domain.
Obviously it's possible, I tried using LDAP Administrator (by Softerra), and there it works.

I tried:

- JclWin32.NetUserGetGroups - Nope. (I can understand this does not work, I can't pass the users password here. Works fine from PC that is on domain)
- JwaLmAccess.NetUserGetLocalGroups - Nope. Also no possiblity to pass password
- NetApi.GetNetUserGroups - same story here
- CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command')... - Nope

I just managed to check the password from non-domain-PC (see [Check username/password in Active Directory from PC that is NOT part of domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064959/check-username-password-in-active-directory-from-pc-that-is-not-part-of-domain) ), so I tried executing the commands when signed on, but this also failed.

Looking around in the Jedi sources, I came across the function "JwaWinLDAP.ldap_search_sW". For me that smells promising as I could pass the LDap-token from the sign-on. However, I didn't find any code samples on how to search a users groups. Is this function the way I should continue to look at?

Can anyone push me in the right direction please? :)
Thanks!

Comment: That logs you into LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) all you can do from there is use LDAP, it doesn't give you access to other API.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can query the AD, you must first logon with a user that has rights to access that AD.

Using an token based on local user logon, will almost surely not give you access to querying the AD.